# How to get Auth Provider in hybridauth?

Tags: php, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

i am using hybridauth to allow my users to sign in to my web site.
i want to know which auth provider (facebook, googel,..) is current user is using.
in this case i am using below script. but it did not get the auth provider.
how to do this. give me some hints?

```
<?php

session_start();

$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/hybridauth/config.php';
require_once('hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php');

$ha = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

$t = $ha->authenticate('Facebook');

if ($t->isUserConnected()) {

    $profile = $t->getUserProfile();
?>

<html>
<body>
<pre><?php echo print_r ($profile); }?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Hybrid_Auth::getConnectedProviders()?

You could also pass-in a particular provider to check to see if a specific one is connected: Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith(provider)

Check the [API doc](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/apidoc.html) for more info.